# Axeslabel doesn't work when using Frame and FrameTicks,

Tags: plotting, labeling

I'm using `FrameTicks` and `Frame` to get a second y-axis. But then my axes labels disappear. I've solved it by using `Framelabel` instead, but was wondering why this happens, and if there is a solution where you can still use `AxisLabel`?

The labels show up in the first plot, but not in the second one.

```
F[x_] := 2 x

Plot[{F[x]}, {x, 1, 100}, 
  AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Subscript["R", \[Null] "⊥,max" \[Null]] [cm] ]} ]

Plot[{F[x]}, {x, 1, 100}, 
  Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{All, All}, {All, None}}, 
  AxesLabel -> {t, HoldForm[Subscript["R", \[Null] "⊥,max" \[Null]] [cm] ]} ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`PlotRangePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangePadding.html) to make enough room in the plot for the axes to appear.

```
Plot[2 x, {x, 1, 100},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {{All, All}, {All, None}},
  PlotRangePadding ->
    {{Scaled[.11], Automatic}, {Scaled[.1], Automatic}},
  AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Subscript["R", "⊥,max"][cm]], t}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Maybe he wanted the labels the other way around, but the general idea works anyway (+1).

Comment: @Jens. It's hard to say. The unframed plot has the `HoldForm[Subscript["R", "\[UpTee],max"][cm]]` label along the x-axis. I thought it best to retain that, so I put `t` on the y-axis.

Comment: Indeed, you're probably right.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "AxesLabel" use "FrameLabel".

```
F[x_] := 2x
Plot[{F[x]}, {x, 1, 100},
 Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}},
 FrameTicks -> {{All, All}, {All, None}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {t, HoldForm[Subscript["R", \[Null]*"\[UpTee],max"*\[Null]][cm]]}]
```

[image: Plot y=2x with frame and labels]